# EaseJS Drag & Drop (Animate CC) Mouse coordinates of Movie Clip

Tags: javascript, html, slider, easeljs, animate-cc

Im working on slider: volume, timeline, screen brighness, ect.
but I cant get actual movie clip X coordinates, all I get is parent HTML5 canvas coordinates, not actual "DragZone" coordinates.

I just dont get it, how do I need to code evt.currentTarget.x to pick specific movieClip coordinates?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer problem was not in evt.currentTarget.x but in my tracking, I was tracking evt.stageX not currentTarget.